# How to get the Server object from SpringApplication.run

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, metrics, embedded-jetty

After looking at the logs, I see that when I run my application, it starts a TomCat WebServer

```
SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
```

Logs:

```
main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path
```

Currently, I have metrics being exposed to a /metrics endpoint and different port. This is done by creating a new Server like this:

```
SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
try {
    Server server = new Server(8080);
    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
    context.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(context);
    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new MetricsServlet()), "/metrics");

    server.start();
    server.join();
```

Logs:

```
STARTED @2880ms ManagedSelector@2f953efd{STARTED} id=1 keys=0 selected=0 updates=0

Selector sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@71a81a3e waiting with 0 keys
STARTED @2880ms SelectorManager@ServerConnector@550ee7e5{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}

ServerConnector@550ee7e5{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080} added {acceptor-0@13526e59,POJO}

Started ServerConnector@550ee7e5{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}

run acceptor-0@13526e59 in QueuedThreadPool[qtp1437654187]@55b0dcab{STARTED,8<=8<=200,i=5,r=-1,q=0}
[ReservedThreadExecutor@74e28667{reserved=0/4,pending=0}]
10:44:35.454 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED @2882ms ServerConnector@550ee7e5{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
10:44:35.455 [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started Server@3e96bacf{STARTING}[11.0.9,sto=0] @2887ms
10:44:35.455 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - STARTED @2887ms Server@3e96bacf{STARTED}[11.0.9,sto=0]
```

The problem is, I want to access the initial TomCat Webserver and add the ServletHolder to it (therefore exposing metrics endpoint but by linking it to tomcat webserver).
I guess my question is, can it be done this way and is it a good practice?

I've tried creating a @GetMapping("/metrics") endpoint within my SampleApplication, but I couldn't add the MetricsServlet that way

Comment: This is quite confusing, you have code and logs that is obviously Jetty, but are asking questions about Tomcat (a different product)?

Comment: Isn‘t [Spring Boot Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/reference/html/actuator.html) designed for this?

Comment: SpringApplication.run() is using Tomcat, essentially i'd like to export my metrics and only use one time of server object.